# What might it mean if all the voltage is dropping over this resistor?

Tags: diodes, motor-controller, multimeter, repair

I'm trying to repair a record player, here's the schematic for what I'm looking at:

https://elektrotanya.com/PREVIEWS/63463243/23432455/pioneer/pioneer_pl-4_sch.pdf_1.png

The problem is that the motor has stopped turning.  Everything up to the control assembly board has power when the player is switched on.  All the voltage drops across the transistor (Q1) collector to emitter on that board.  However, I also noticed that all the voltage drops across the 2.2k resistor (R2) which links the base and collector.  I'm not sure how that could be given the presence of the diode (D2), which should isolate that part of the circuit from ground.  I would expect that voltage drop to be 0.

My initial hasty conclusion from my readings was that the resistor was bad, but I wasn't stopping to think about the fact that the Q1 base should be isolated from ground.  Thinking about it more leads me to believe D2 may be bad, or one of the capacitors (C3, C2).

So my questions are:

- Am I correct in thinking the voltage over R2 should be 0 if it's bad and the other components are otherwise working properly?
- Can I find out for certain what the problem is short of ordering  D2, C2, and C3, and replacing them all?
- Is there a way to know if it would be safe to remove D2 and see if the motor turns, or would that fry everything?

Comment: The 2.2 kohm resistor may be defect. What is the exact voltage across the Z-diode D2? Almost zero (=transistor failure) or true zero?

Comment: the components have labels, please use them in your description

Comment: Its could be the zener or the cap below the resistor. I'd guess the cap first, that should be easier to find then a 30v zener.   You could remove the cap and test with a DVM (on Ohm setting) to see if one is shorted, (if good they show an increasing resistance as the capacitor charges).

Comment: That's a neat trick to figure out if the capacitor is good or not.  At your suggestion I removed C3 to test it, and while I was at it R2 and D2.  I'm always reluctant to remove things in case they might be good and I burn them up or otherwise destroy them in the process of trying to get them off the board.  C3 at least seems to be good, the resistor measures right around its nominal value.  D2 meanwhile shows 0 ohms going either direction, which makes me think it is in fact acting as a short?